# Changing source of image inside a class on click Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a really simple code where every time I click on an image it changes the source.  I Want also to display this image in hover but that would be the next step after I can make it work on click.

This is my HTML

```
 <div class="seats-row-A">
                <img id="A1" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
                <img id="A2" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
                <img id="A3" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
                <img id="A4" class="seat-unique"  src="chair.svg" >
                <img id="A5" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
                <img id="A6" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
                <img id="A7"  class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
</div>
```

This is my JS

```
seatsUnclicked= document.getElementsByClassName("seat-unique");
for(var i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++)
    {        
        seatsUnclicked[i].onclick = function(){
        seatsUnclicked[i].src = "chairhover.svg";
    }

}
```

Comment: use `let` or a closure to make sure that `i` has the expected value and not `seatsUnclicked.length` instead (which would lead to your null error). Or use the event argument to get the target element correctly

Answer (score 1):

This is typical problem of the scope of the variable.In your case onclick event will occur sometime in future.By that time the for-loop have finished its execution and the value of `i` is set to the length of the html collection.

Before `let` one of the solution was to create an Immediately invoking function expression and pass the value of the `i` , This value will be accepted as a parameter.In this way with closure the value of `i` is preserved.

In ES6 with new keyword `let` there is no need of creating a closure and `IIFE`

```js
var seatsUnclicked = document.getElementsByClassName("seat-unique");
//SOLUTION 1


for (var i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++) {
  (function(x) {
    seatsUnclicked[x].onclick = function() {
      seatsUnclicked[x].src = "chairhover.svg";
    }
  }(i))
}

//SOLUTION 2

for (let i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++) {

  seatsUnclicked[i].onclick = function() {
    seatsUnclicked[i].src = "chairhover.svg";
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="seats-row-A">
  <img id="A1" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A2" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A3" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A4" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A5" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A6" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A7" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to use [event propagation](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) instead, then you do not need to attach an event handler to all separate images

```js
let seatContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.seats-row-A')[0];
// use event-propagation catch all clicks on seats-row-a, and handle clicks that wait
seatContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.src) {
    // no image
    return;
  }
  if (e.target.src.includes('chair.svg')) {
    e.target.src = 'chairhover.svg';
  } else {
    e.target.src = 'chair.svg';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="seats-row-A">
  <img id="A1" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
  <img id="A2" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
  <img id="A3" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
  <img id="A4" class="seat-unique"  src="chair.svg" >
  <img id="A5" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
  <img id="A6" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg" >
  <img id="A7"  class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
</div>
```

Or, you can create `i` as a [block scoped variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), using `let` as declaration as opposed to your current `var` (function scoped variable)

```
for (let i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++) {        
    seatsUnclicked[i].onclick = function() {
        seatsUnclicked[i].src = "chairhover.svg";
    }
}
```

Or you could use the [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click), that points to your element (a bit like the event propagation in the first example)

```
function handleElementClicked( e ) {
  if (e.target.src.includes('chair.svg')) {
    e.target.src = 'chairhover.svg';
  } else {
    e.target.src = 'chair.svg';
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++) {        
    seatsUnclicked[i].onclick = handleElementClicked;
}
```

Or, you could [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) your indexer to your calling function

```
for (var i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++) {        
    seatsUnclicked[i].onclick = function( index ) {
        seatsUnclicked[index].src = "chairhover.svg";
    }.bind( null, i );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

To avoid unecessary class names and inline onClick js, you can use `querySelectorAll` instead and add a click listener to each one like this:

```
let seatsUnclicked = document.querySelectorAll("img");

function changeImage() {
this.src="chairhover.svg";
}

seatsUnclicked.forEach(img => {
img.addEventListener('click', changeImage);
})
```

---

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/866vf8a1/

Answer (score 0):

**Couple of things I observed:**

1. You have to use setAttribute to set the attribute
2. inside the function you used : seatsUnclicked[i].src = "chairhover.svg";

   here i is always equal = seatsUnclicked.length

   so it gives undefined element. so you get error cannot set the property of undefined.
3. user event.currentTarget.setAttribute:

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/hgfeh9zw/

```
<div class="seats-row-A">
<img id="A1" class="seat-unique" 
src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/64/sign-check-icon.png" >
<img id="A2" class="seat-unique" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/64/sign-check-icon.png" >
<img id="A3" class="seat-unique" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/64/sign-check-icon.png" >
<img id="A4" class="seat-unique"  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/64/sign-check-icon.png" >
<img id="A5" class="seat-unique" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/64/sign-check-icon.png" >
<img id="A6" class="seat-unique" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/64/sign-check-icon.png" >
<img id="A7"  class="seat-unique" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/64/sign-check-icon.png">
</div>
<script> 
  window.onload= function(){
  seatsUnclicked= document.getElementsByClassName("seat-unique");
   for(var i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++)
   { 
      seatsUnclicked[i].onclick = function(event){
      event.currentTarget.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b43bbab9d16d030a8744f17ca9c1da8d?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG');
    }
  }

 }

  </script>
```